# HTTP authentication on QlikView server from Java application

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, qlikview

hello,
I am developing a Java struts2 based application which is using QlikView as reporting tool. This application is using NTLM single sign on mechanism. when the user logs into the  application and clicks on reports tab, he/she should see the QlikView report.

few imp points: 
1. we have a generic user id which needs to be authenticated on QlikView server. so being in a SSO application, we have to impersonate the user by changing the user details in
 the http request.
2. when I use iFrame in the JSP page it gives me a popup to enter user credentials to view QlikView report. How can i get rid of it and let the user directly view the report with any more login.

Note: The user who is using the application will not be requesting for report, rather a
 generic ID will be requesting for it. we need to impersonate the user in the http
 request and do an automatic login.

please let me know if u need anymore clarification. any help on this would be thankful.